# How to connect two view controllers to one button in storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

Up to now, there is a button in a view controller (let's call it Main View Controller). What I want is: if it satisfies a certain condition, when I press the button, the segue would lead to View Controller A; if not, when I press the button, it would lead to View Controller B.
But it seems that one button can only have one segue from it, so I wonder whether what I want is possible to be achieved in storyboard???
Thanks in advance!!!

If this question is too basic for you, I am so sorry. I am still a very starter in iOS programming.

Comment: you need to put if else condition as well in you button action for detect which vc going to be push or pop.

Comment: @NitinGohel Yes, but my problem now is that I cannot get two segues with two identifiers from one button. Could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Jenny, Let's assume if you would be able to connect 2 segues from single button then how can it be possible to put a condition to decide which segue to be used on button click, I mean you have to implement the IBAction for that button. And if you are going to implement IBAction then there is no point in connecting the seques to perform actions. That's the reason why xcode does not allow multiple segues on single button.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to create a segue from the viewController itself to the destination. You can do this for each viewController and give them appropriate identifiers.

[image]

Then you hook up your button with an `IBAction` and decide which segue to perform

[image]