# Perform a Segue When Page is Pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm trying to define a segue that will pass variables to the second view controller when the second view controller is pressed.

This is what I done so far:

[image]

[image]

I created the segue from one view controller to the second view controller, and my problem is that the segue is never called when I press the page of the second view controller.

How can I perform the segue when the second view controller page is pressed?

Thanks!

EDIT: I need to perform the segue without changing the ViewControlles.. Can I do it?

Comment: Where you have written a button press action?

Comment: did you implement the prepareForSegue method

Comment: @YogeshMv That's the problem. I don't want a button to do that. I have Tab Bar Controller with 3 pages, and only when one of them is clicked I want the segue to perform.

Comment: @LukePatterson The first image is in the 'prepareForSegue' method

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your segue like this:

[image]

Then be sure to have in the view your pushing from this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if (segue.identifier == "mySeague") {
        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
        destinationVC.testVariable = "Hello world"
    }
}
```

This is a small thing but you should remove the space from your segue identifier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to do it with a button. I have Tab Bar Controller with 3 pages, and only when one of them is clicked I want the segue to perform.

Comment: @random I wondering how do you  convert video to gif to post answers.if you don't mind....cheers

Comment: @HelpPleasee check out this answer, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086416/how-to-connect-two-view-controllers-to-one-button-in-storyboard You'll need to programmatically perform the segue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you linked your segue to 2 controllers, that way, you don't have anything that call the action.

If you want to call it on a button tap, ctrl + drag and drop from the button to the destination view.

If you want to call it on the tap on the first view controller, add a `gestureTapRecognizer` on your controller and ctrl + drag and drop from that gesture recognizer (in your document outline on the left of the storyboard) to your destination controller.