# How to programmatically seque to multiple view controllers from a button

Tags: swift, button, segue, viewcontroller

I have a view controller with a lot (36) of buttons, and I want each of these buttons to segue to a particular view controller based on a variable that was set earlier in the program. In other words, any button could potentially go to 15 different view controllers based on a variable that was sent to the viewcontroller containing the buttons...

I think I  can make this work if I click and drag each button to every viewcontroller... but it seems silly and messy.

I tried doing something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if variable == "Whatever" {

    let send = segue.destination as! AViewController
        send.variablesent = (sender as! UIButton).title(for: .normal)!}
}
```

But this only works if I click and drag the button in the storyboard to the "AViewController".

Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Use each button with tag. & u can identify each with sender.tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you can make segue from `SourceViewController` to `DestinationViewController` instead of from `Button` to `Controller`, After that when you call `perfromSegue` in your button action then pass button reference as `sender` in `perfromSegue` call.

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueIdentifier", sender: sender)
}
```

Now in `prepareForSegue` cast sender to `UIButton` and set title according to it.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if variable == "Whatever" {
        let send = segue.destination as! AViewController
        if let button = sender as? UIButton {
            send.variablesent = button.titleLabel?.text ?? "Default value"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm trying to figure out what the "segueIdentifier" should be, and how I can get to multiple viewcontrollers from the same button. It's not clicking for me yet. Any direction? Thanks!

Comment: I'm new to all this, and didn't have enough background knowledge to understand your answer. Now, I got it to work and now understand your answer. This was a helpful guide to connect what I didn't understand: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31086536/7729572

Comment: Welcome mate :)