# How to perform different segue based on condition from a button click in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm building an app in which a button takes you to a profile registry view if you open the app for the first time and into another if you open the app any other time. How can I accomplish this programmatically, everything i have seen only connects the button to one view.

```
@IBAction func NextViewController(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if launchedBefore  {
        print("Not first launch.")

    } else {
        print("First launch, setting UserDefault.")


        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't like your solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think, You are trying to connect the button to perform segue with multiple ViewController Right?? which is not possible

Instead  that you have to connect segue between  View Controllers

**Adding a segue between two viewControllers:**

From the Interface Builder, ctrl + drag between the two viewControllers that you want to link. You should see:

[image]

And now based on you condition you should perform segue with identifiers like below:

```
@IBAction func NextViewController(_ sender: UIButton) {
            if launchedBefore  {
        /*Use the Identifier you given in story Board*/
               self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "otherVC", sender: self)

            } else {
    /*Use the Identifier you given in story Board*/
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "register", sender: self))
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
            }
        }
```

For more Descriptive answer about segue see the answer [How to connect two view controllers to one button in storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086416/how-to-connect-two-view-controllers-to-one-button-in-storyboard)

Comment: Man, you deserve a medal:) Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: PEOPLE PLEASE UPVOTE JAYDEEP!